# what's the font used in the new Material Design, And how to get it?

Tags: fonts, google-material-design, google

What is the font used in the new google Material design interface?
And if it's possible, how do I get it?

This is the interface in case:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google Sans](https://devfiles.co/download/vSxQjI5P/Google-Sans-Font.zip) via devfiles.co

> Google Sans Font or Product Sans font is a custom and geometric sans serif font developed along with the new Google Logo and identity system.

[+ info](https://pradeepsingh.com/google-sans-font-product-sans/)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering! That exactly what I was looking for! But just one thing, the page that you provided has a download link, but the page also says it's not open source like other fonts, so I don't think I can use it in my apps even If as long as I saw it says nothing about the licence, am I right?

Comment: I really don't know, read [this page](https://pradeepsingh.com/google-sans-font-product-sans/)